# What should $TERM be on Mac OSX 10.6.6?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

`echo $TERM` gives me `xterm-color`. Is that right? I'm having [issues with vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729108/vim-replaces-lines-when-i-move-to-a-new-line) and was told to change it to `dtterm`. Why?

I've learned that I can change this value in Terminal.app Preferences... under the Advanced tab: Declare terminal as:

Comment: Only the person who told you that can answer why. When it comes to setting `$TERM` there's a lot of paranoia and misinformation around. Ideally, `$TERM` should always be set to a value that is correct for whatever terminal emulator you're using. Only occasionally is there a reason to select a variation, to disable or modify specific features, e.g., `xterm` vs. `xterm1`. Rarely, it's sometimes necessary to customize the value to work around a problem, usually with a program that either has a bug or isn't configurable enough.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `xterm-color` is the default for `Terminal.app`; it's the most compatible with, well, everything. You can see when you open the preferences window for the terminal:

[image: Terminal Dialog]

You can change it to `dtterm` in the menu:

[image: Terminal Dialog]